# Does the timestamp matter for a new transaction? About same gasPrice TX order inside a mined block

Tags: go-ethereum, gas, mining, blocks, full-node

I want to send a **Transaction to follow a specific Transaction in the same block**.

Now I can guaranty my Transaction exactly been placed in the same Block.
But there are a lots of other TXs between my Tx and my target Tx.

All of those Txs include mine, my target are using the same gasPrice.

I learned a lot finally found the basic strategy for ordering is `GasPrice+FirstSeenTime`. (Let's ignore the Nonce that only considered for duplicate Txs from same account).

I wonder how the miner's full node/validator decide `FirstSeenTime`.
Is `FirstSeenTime` propaganda from peer by peer? Or it is generated when Tx is reached miner's node?

If the answer is the first one. I think I can build a full node that can modify my Tx's firstSeenTime, then propaganda it to other peers.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way to ensure specific transaction order inside the block - use [flashbots](https://docs.flashbots.net/flashbots-auction/searchers/quick-start). It allows you to send a bundle of transactions guaranteeing that they will be mined in a block in this exact order next to each other. Futhermore, if one of the bundled transactions reverts the entire bundle will not be included in a block so you don't have to pay gas fees for reverts.